# Android - Icon does not show in Google Play (formerly Android Market)

Tags: android, icons

I have developed an Android app. I launched it in different phones, and the icons are my icons. But when I upload the [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file to [Google Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play), it appears as the [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) default icon. In my resource file there are some Android default icons named "ic_launcher", but I do not link them. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you don't link them Play Store will use those icons if you have not provided anything else.

Search ic_launcher in your project and replace that with the icon you want to show. Remember **Launcher icons for display on Google Play must be 512x512 pixels.**

see [this guide](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) for designing icons.

Answer (score 0):

Check and modify the file `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ico_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```